# Entity Framework : INSTEAD OF TRIGGER works first time on INSERT but fails on UPDATE

Tags: entity-framework, triggers

As per the title, this trigger works like a charm when inserting a row for the first time. It get´s added to the database. But when trying to insert a row again, I only get a `DbUpdateException`. I have read all threads and tried to set `@@IDENTITY`, in update clause. I have tried to return id_column inside update statement to no avail.

Error message:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

I got this for insert but then I started to return the ID, but this does not seem to apply for the `UPDATE` part of the trigger.

Anyone have a clue on how Entity Framework wants this to be done?

C# code:

```
try
{
    context.MarketMakerInstrumentValues.Add(mmiv);
    context.SaveChanges();
}         
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    var dbcontext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    var refreshableObjects = (from entry in dbcontext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged)
                              where entry.EntityKey != null
                              select entry.Entity).ToList();
    context.MarketMakerInstrumentValues.Attach((MarketMakerInstrumentValues)refreshableObjects[0]);
    dbcontext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, refreshableObjects);
                    
    try
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        var eee = exe;
    }
}
```

SQL Server trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[handlemarketmakervalues]
ON [dbo].[MarketMakerInstrumentValues]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM [dbo].MarketMakerInstrumentValues AS mmiv, inserted AS i  
               -- JOIN [inserted] AS i ON i.[instrument_values_avanza_id] =  mmiv.[instrument_values_avanza_id]
               WHERE i.[instrument_values_avanza_id] = mmiv.[instrument_values_avanza_id]
                 AND DATEPART(minute, i.[instrument_values_datetime]) = DATEPART(minute, mmiv.[instrument_values_datetime])
                 AND DATEPART(hour, i.[instrument_values_datetime]) = DATEPART(hour, mmiv.[instrument_values_datetime]))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE mmiv 
        SET mmiv.[instrument_values_max] = 
                CASE
                    WHEN mmiv.[instrument_values_max] > i.[instrument_values_max]
                        THEN mmiv.[instrument_values_max]
                        ELSE i.[instrument_values_max]
                END,
            mmiv.[instrument_values_min] = 
                CASE
                    WHEN mmiv.[instrument_values_min] < i.[instrument_values_min]
                        THEN mmiv.[instrument_values_min]
                        ELSE i.[instrument_values_min]
                END,
            mmiv.[instrument_values_value] = i.[instrument_values_value]
            -- @@IDENTITY = mmiv.[instrument_values_id]
        FROM 
            [dbo].MarketMakerInstrumentValues mmiv, [inserted] i
        WHERE 
            DATEPART(minute, i.[instrument_values_datetime]) = DATEPART(minute, mmiv.[instrument_values_datetime])
            AND DATEPART(hour, i.[instrument_values_datetime]) = DATEPART(hour, mmiv.[instrument_values_datetime])
            AND i.[instrument_values_date] = mmiv.[instrument_values_date]
            AND i.[instrument_values_avanza_id] = mmiv.[instrument_values_avanza_id]
    
        SELECT NULL
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MarketMakerInstrumentValues ([instrument_values_value],
                          [instrument_values_datetime],
                          [instrument_values_avanza_id],
                          [instrument_values_date],
                          [instrument_values_max],
                          [instrument_values_min])
            SELECT 
                [instrument_values_value],
                [instrument_values_datetime],
                [instrument_values_avanza_id],
                [instrument_values_date],
                [instrument_values_max],
                [instrument_values_min] 
            FROM
                [inserted]

        SELECT [instrument_values_id] 
        FROM [dbo].[MarketMakerInstrumentValues] 
        WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
          AND [instrument_values_id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Comment: I suggest you unit test this by running some tests directly in SSMS or Azure Data Studio. See if you get a better error message

Comment: I also suggest that you'd be better off encasing this logic in a stored procedure rather than using triggers. Triggers are just trouble.

Comment: Does _for the first time_ mean this only works on an empty table? or does it mean something else?